# Why does Blazor call OnValidSubmit without pressing a button with type submit?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have an edit form and everytime I click a button even though it is not of type submit, Blazor calls `OnValidSubmit` but I don't know why. Below there is a simplified excerpt of my code (split in two blocks for better syntax highlighting in Stackoverflow, in reality it is one file):

```html
@page "/BaseConfiguration"
@using TeslaSolarCharger.Shared.Dtos.BaseConfiguration
@inject HttpClient HttpClient

@if (_dtoBaseConfiguration == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <EditForm Model="@_dtoBaseConfiguration" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
        @*Next line is the button I am talking about*@
        <p><button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="AddNewGridHeader">Add new header</button></p>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </EditForm>
}
```

```cs
@code {
    private DtoBaseConfiguration? _dtoBaseConfiguration;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _dtoBaseConfiguration = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<DtoBaseConfiguration>("/api/BaseConfiguration/GetBaseConfiguration");
    }

    private void AddNewGridHeader()
    {
    }

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        await HttpClient.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/BaseConfiguration/UpdateBaseConfiguration", _dtoBaseConfiguration);
    }
}
```

When I press the button `Add new header` The `HandleValidSubmit` method is called and my Blazor app sends the put request. Why is that the case? How can I avoid that issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="AddNewGridHeader">Add new header</button>
```

to **type** "button"

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="AddNewGridHeader">Add new header</button>
```

If you don't specify the button type, it **defaults** to submit.

- submit — Submits the current form data. (This is default.)
- reset — Resets data in the current form.
- button — Just a button. Its effects must be controlled by something
  else

submit - Default
reset - used to reset forms
button - events must be handled manually